# How can I get the last running process

Tags: c#

```
Process[] processList1 = Process.GetProcesses();
int size = processList1.Length;

MessageBox.Show("" + processList1[size - 1]);
```

Comment: what do you mean by last running process ? process which runs first or terminated recently?

Comment: the last process run by the pc

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the most recent process, you can achieve that by ordering the list by start time:

```
Process mostRecent = Process.GetProcesses().OrderBy(p => p.StartTime).Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Process[] processList1;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        processList1 = Process.GetProcesses();
    }
   //set timer1.Interval to 5000

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Process item in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (!processList1.Contains(item))
            {
                //get all new Processes
            }
        }
        processList1 = Process.GetProcesses();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code.
this code gets all processes and compare the start date if you open a new process it will show the name of it in label1 that should be in your form.

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process[] processList1 = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();
        DateTime min = processList1[0].StartTime;

        Process last = new Process();
        foreach (Process a in processList1)
        {

            try
            {
                if (DateTime.Compare(a.StartTime, min) >= 0)
                {
                    last = a;
                    min = a.StartTime;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }

        }
        label1.Text = last.ProcessName;
    }
```

Comment: Yes that is true, and for that reason try and catch is used. only accessible process can be evaluated. In sorting, using this model ignores  Access Denied exception and for other processes it works.